# Translations not working, Magento_Checkout

Tags: magento2, localisation, bug

I'm facing the problems with Finnish translations (Magento ver. 2.1.7). The main pages are translated but all the Magento_Checkout translations are in English.

It seems that this is bug in the Magento 2 implementation,
e.g. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2951

Once I got it working with this:

> ```
> find . -name js-translation.json -exec rm -rf {} ;
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fi_FI
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> php bin/magento cache:clean
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

I though that this will be the permanent solution... but I was totally wrong.

When the set of commands were rerun, all the checkout related texts are back in English.

All solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to Magento bug. In `vendor/magento/module-translation/Model/Json/PreProcessor.php`

```
$area = $this->areaList->getArea($areaCode);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

needs to be:

```
$area = $this->areaList->getArea($areaCode);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_DESIGN);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8508#issuecomment-279332346